# In Python 2.7, what would be the way to check if raw_input is not in a list of strings?

Tags: python

I cut off 177 lines beforehand to save space, in that I had defending_list , which contained all of the possible ways to type the different shields I had, then the shields were broken up to further check what was given, and give the appropriate stat boosts. If the input was not in the defending_list, I want the people to have to re-enter a selection until they type one of the things in the list.

```
print "these are the possible shields you can use:" ', '.join(defendList)
Choose_A_Shield = raw_input('choose a valid shield from the list please:')
if Choose_A_Shield in sheild:
    defending_defense = base_defense + 6
elif Choose_A_Shield in large_Shield:
    defending_defense = base_defense + 9
elif Choose_A_Shield in nothing:
    print "you decide to go without a shield"
    defending_defense = 10
Choose_A_Shield = raw_input('choose a shield from the list to use:')
Choose_A_Shield = raw_input('choose a shield from the list to use:')
while Choose_A_Shield != item in defending_list:
    Choose_A_Shield = raw_input('choose a valid shield from the list please:')
    if Choose_A_Shield in sheild:
        defending_defense = base_defense + 6
    elif Choose_A_Shield in large_Shield:
        defending_defense = base_defense + 9
    elif Choose_A_Shield in nothing:
        print "you decide to go without a shield"
        defending_defense = 10
```

i'm trying to create a statement like this for an equipment setup in a text based game in python, however, looking around, I cannot find an easy way to check if it is NOT in the list, then proceed in a loop until the input is in the list.

This is my current error message with this setup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 170, in story
NameError: global name 'item' is not defined
```

Can you please show me a way to preform this task?

also, if you are willing, can you tell me why the code:

```
    print "these are the possible shields you can use:" ', '.join(defendList)
```

gives me some text like this:

```
nothingthese are the possible shields you can use:, shield
```

the list that the string joins with contains "nothing" from the start.(as in, an item for if the person wants to fight barehanded) If you pick up an item like shield or large shield, it adds the shield or large shield to it

these are both huge issues for me, because I am planning on using the same  system to let the player select a weapon.

Comment: FWIW, you have a variable named `sheild` instead of `shield`; that could get confusing. Also, you should try to eliminate repetition in your code, see [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I suspect that you could radically reduce the size of those 177 lines you cut off if you adopt the DRY principle (and possibly use some functions in the itertools module), but that's a topic for another question.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question should be pretty easy:

```
while Choose_A_Shield not in defending_list:
```

For proper joining, add +

```
print "these are the possible shields you can use: " + ', '.join(defendList)
```

Comment: well that was simple. I feel stupid now. the "not" in there usually doesn't work for me for some reason, so i didn't think to use it.

Comment: @DjBarrington Don't feel stupid :) I'm glad it works!

Comment: @DjBarrington: When the Python interpreter sees 2 or more adjacent literal strings (separated only by whitespace, including newlines) it concatenates them. So `"stuff" ', '.join(defendList)` is equivalent to `"stuff, ".join(defendList)` , which joins the strings in `defendList` using `"stuff, "` as the separator. Note that this automatic concatenation _only_ happens with literal strings. If you try to do `a='a';b='b';c=a b` you'll just get a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of equipment is `list_of_shields`, you can achieve what you want like this:

```
choice = raw_input('choose a valid shield from the list please:')
while choice not in list_of_shields:
    choice = raw_input('choose a valid shield from the list please:')
```

Answer (score 0):

well that was simple:
 To check if a raw_input is in a list of strings like this, you simply need to use 'inpt not in blah_List'. 
And to add to strings without them getting all weird, you have to close the quote and use a '+'.

is this good enough of an answer? There's not much more I can say... wait... is this required?

Comment: someone else in another question told me that I should answer my questions...so... I don't know... I did not look into it...

Comment: You _can_ answer your own questions but you aren't _required_ to do so. Sometimes, people come up with a good question that they already now the answer to, as mentioned in [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: (cont) Another reason to self-answer is when you get a bunch of helpful answers and you want to unify and summarise the information in those answers. If you do that, it's good to reference each of the original authors by name in your summary. Similarly, if the answers by others don't completely answer your question but lead you to finding the correct answer yourself, then you may like to write a self-answer. That situation often comes up when dealing with homework questions, since many answerers will not post complete answers in that situation - instead, they'll post helpful hints.